# In Excel how can I select the most recent date from an array using a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an array of 100+ dates, I want to use a formula to sort through the date and in one variation show the most recent one and the least recent one.

So for I've sorted the arrays but I only want to show one record

e.g. given the below array

| Date |
| --- |
| 30/01/1990 |
| 30/01/2000 |
| 30/01/2010 |
| 30/01/2020 |

I want to show

| Most Recent | Earliest |
| --- | --- |
| 30/01/2020 | 30/01/1990 |

Note these would be with two separate forumulas

Comment: Have you tried MAX and MIN functions?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio tried the Min and Max functions and it did not work, so raised the question. Later on realizing that it did not work because excel was not picking up the source data as a date so that is why it did not work.  Fixed that and then it was fine.